# SQL Server : remove duplicates from count()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a report in a SQL Server database. I will show it's code first and then describe what it does and where is problem.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(e.flowid) AS [count], 
    t.name AS [process], 
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, e.dtcr) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MONTH, e.dtcr)), 2) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DAY, e.dtcr)), 2) AS VARCHAR) AS [day]
FROM 
    dbo.[Event] e  
JOIN 
    dbo.Flow f ON e.flowid = f.id 
JOIN 
    dbo.WorkOrder o ON f.workorderno = o.number 
                    AND o.treenodeid IN (26067, 26152, 2469, 1815, 1913) -- only from requested processes 
JOIN 
    dbo.TreeNode t ON o.treenodeid = t.id -- for process name in select statement
JOIN  
    dbo.Product p ON f.productid = p.id
                  AND p.materialid NOT IN (26094, 27262, 27515, 27264, 28192, 28195, 26090, 26092, 26093, 27065, 26969, 27471, 28351, 28353, 28356, 28976, 27486, 29345, 29346, 27069, 28653, 28654, 26735, 26745, 28686) -- exclude unwanted family codes
WHERE 
    e.pass = 1 -- only passed units
    AND e.treenodeid IN (9036, 9037, 9038, 9039, 12594, 26330) -- only from requested events
    AND e.dtcr BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-05-31 23:59:59.999' -- only from requested time interval 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR, e.dtcr), DATEPART(MONTH, e.dtcr), DATEPART(DAY, e.dtcr), t.name
ORDER BY 
    [day]
```

What query does is count units that passed specific events in a time periods (with some filters).

Important tables are:

1. Event - basically log for units passing specific events.
2. Product - list of units.

Output is something like this:

```
COUNT   PROCESS     DAY
71      Process-1   2015-12-01
1067    Process-2   2015-12-01
8       Process-3   2015-12-01
3       Process-4   2015-12-01
15      Process-1   2015-12-02
276     Process-2   2015-12-02
47      Process-3   2015-12-02
54      Process-4   2015-12-02
```

It does well but there is an issue. In some specific cases unit can pass same event several times and this query counts every such passing. I need to count every unit only once.

"Duplicated" records are in Event table. They have different dates and ids. Same for all records I need to count only once is flowid. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: Do you mean `count(distinct flowid)`?

Comment: Are you serious, is it really that simple? (Yes it is. I tried and it works! Now I feel like an idiot.) Please add it as answer so I can tag it as correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count each flowid only once, do `count(distinct flowid)`, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct e.flowid) AS [count], 
    t.name AS [process], 
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, e.dtcr) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MONTH, e.dtcr)), 2) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(DAY, e.dtcr)), 2) AS VARCHAR) AS [day]
FROM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the first time that something passes the threshold.  You can get the first time using `row_number()`.  This can be tricky with the additional conditions on the query.  This modification might work for you:

```
select sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt,
       . . .
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by eventid order by e.dtcr) as seqnum
      from event e
      where e.pass = 1 and  -- only passed units
            e.treenodeid IN (9036, 9037, 9038, 9039, 12594, 26330) and
            e.dtcr >= '2015-12-01' AND e.dtcr < '2016-06-01'
     ) e join 
     . . .
```

You don't specify how the same event is identified for the duplicates.  The above uses `eventid` for this purpose.